# Using IsPickVal() function inside Email Templates

Tags: email-template, picklist, merge-field, if

I tried using the following ISPICKVAL formula within an email template as shown:
[image]

MQP Type is a pick list on the Task Object. I have run integration code(Python under AWS) which sets the pick list value to "RAQ" and I can see the pick list value within the integration log and also on the task record. However, the email notification (sent from process builder flow)  doesn't seem to know what to do with the IF() function with ISPICKVAL() function results.

Here is what this email notification gives me:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: not all formula expressions work inside of HTML email templates - if you switch to a VF email template, the formulas will work

Answer (score 0):

After readingboth the response from **cropredy**
as well as additional SF help topics on the subject, I found that there was an Idea on SF success that was pushing to have email template merge fields us advanced functions like IF and ISPICKVAL but according to SF support there is no way to accomplish this unless you use VF email template or a custom field which makes sense because Apex mark up language has the libraries to accommodate functions using VF so I will give that a try.  Thanks to **cropredy**